# Azure Devops : No test assemblies found on the test machine matching the source filter criteria or no tests discovered matching test filter criteria

Tags: testing, azure-devops, continuous-integration, automated-tests, specflow

I'm trying to run automated tests from test plans in Azure devops.
I've added a task in my automated test pipeline to generate artifacts.
I've created a release of the test pipeline with the following tasks :

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is that when I run my test from my test plan, I have the following error saying that there is no test assemblies :

```
2022-09-22T15:27:08.6879981Z ##[error]ExecutionAndPublish.Run : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.TestsNotFoundException: No test assemblies found on the test machine matching the source filter criteria or no tests discovered matching test filter criteria. Verify that test assemblies are present on the machine and test filter criteria is correct.
2022-09-22T15:27:08.6882575Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.Execution.Run(ExecutionStateContext stateModelContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2022-09-22T15:27:08.6883354Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.ExecutionAndPublish.Run(ExecutionStateContext stateModelContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2022-09-22T15:27:08.6885647Z ##[error]The slice of type 'Execution' is 'Aborted' because of the error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.TestsNotFoundException: No test assemblies found on the test machine matching the source filter criteria or no tests discovered matching test filter criteria. Verify that test assemblies are present on the machine and test filter criteria is correct.
```

[image: logs]

Comment: I embedded the screenshots of the build configuration, because those are useful. Please [edit] your question to include the error message as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Most Microsoft test Execution Engines including MSTest have a default pattern they use to discovery test Assemblies which is

`**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*.test*.dll;-:**\obj\**`

Since you are not showing the Files copied I'll have to assume that you might not have any dlls that match these patterns

To ovverride this behaviour you'll need to ensure you are using the version 2.x of the Test Execution Task and Update the Test Files Glob Patterns
[image: Test Pattern]